# WPF not releasing memory on certain computers

Tags: wpf, vb.net, memory

On certain computers I have a WPF application that doesn't release memory when working with it. For instance when sending a document to the printer, on most computers it's releasing memory all the 2-3 seconds (it's going up for maybe 200 megs then coming back down), which is normal behaviour and when the printing is done I go back to my initial memory state.

But on some computers (over 20 computers installed and only one is giving me this issue) it's not freeing the memory. It keeps piling up. I don't mind seeing memory going to 1.5 Gb as long as it's releasing it in the end, but it's not and I get an OutOfMemoryException.

I don't have full access to the problematic computer (they're a client's computer we installed a week ago and we just saw this problem) so I can't really test it but it's a standard Windows 7 Pro x64, with 10Gb of RAM and aside from that, it's working like a charm.

Also it's not ONLY when printing. The application is kind of a PDF viewer and everytime a new page is loaded for the user, the previous page is freed from memory. Again, it's working fine on most PC, but not in these case.

Is there anything that could prevent the memory from being released? I can't seem to find a similar problem  anywhere on the web.

EDIT: Okay I got a hold of the computer for an hour. I was able to test two things :

1. GC.Collect() didn't arrange anything (I even forced it with GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer)
2. I tried disposing of the DocumentPage in my Paginator, no luck. I also kept a reference of a ViewModel I was using to display my page on printing, I tried disposing it : didn't work.

What I can say is that in both cases it must be because of the images displayed in my pages. Here's the function I call to get a new page image :

```
'First I get the path to the images
Dim path As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}.png", Me.TemporaryFolderPath, page.PageId)
Dim imgSource As CachedBitmap

'If the file doesn't exist
If Not IO.File.Exists(path) Then
     'A function is called which creates the png file for next uses (this way the first loading is slow, but the next times it's faster)
     imgSource = Pdf.GetPageImage(page.PageNumber, path)
Else
     'If the file exists I instantiate a new BitmapImage
     Dim img As New BitmapImage

     'And I load it in a stream
     Using stream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(path)
          'I apply the stream to my image
          img.BeginInit()
          img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
          img.StreamSource = stream
          img.EndInit()

          'Flush, close, dispose of my stream
          stream.Flush()
          stream.Close()
     End Using

     'And I create a CachedBitmap with this image (which is almost like an ImageSource)
     imgSource = New CachedBitmap(img, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)
     img = Nothing
End If

'If my ImageSource is something, I freeze it so that the memory is freed afterwards
If imgSource IsNot Nothing Then imgSource.Freeze()

Return imgSource
```

All this (freezing the image, setting the cacheOption to OnLoad, loading from a stream) I did to avoid memory leaks. My first attempt to load an image has a huge leak and I refactored my function so that I didn't have this problem anymore.

Is there anything there that could be the problem?

Comment: suppose you've tried forcing GC?

Comment: I have to admit... I didn't. Since it's bad practice I didn't want to force a GC.Collect() (which seemed unnecessary since it's working on most computer).

Comment: I can't think off hand another way of solving 'OutOfMemoryExcpetion' other than that, or by sending in smaller packets. would it be possible just to 'patch' that specific machine, as obvoiusly it must have *some* underlying issue?

Comment: Go old style approach, if possible. Remove all event handlers by hand, set everything to null, don't rely on GC. Try to release everything you can. Also, check SP version of the OS and .NET Framework installed there, and compare with other computers. I would do that if I were you. Also, maybe you should try to reproduce the problem when sending to some software PDF creator, not real printer.

Comment: It might be the print driver.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll try the GC.Collect on the client's machine tomorrow just to check if it changed something. Patching only one computer could be okay but if have to, it means there's something wrong with my code in any case. @XMight : I'll check this. I already tried with PDF Creator (also tried PDF Complete and MS One Note) to be sure it had nothing to do with printer or printer's driver. Anyways it's not working right when using the file too so it's not a printer problem.

Comment: Did you make sure to call `.Dispose` for any object (remember stuff you define inline!) that implements IDisposable?

Comment: Well I had a memory leak two months ago when viewing the document (not on printing though) so I did a thorough memory leak research using ANTS memory profiler and now everything looks like it's disposing just fine... But nobody has an idea of WHY memory releasing would behave differentely between two roughly same machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my problem was that I was keeping my current page image in a ReadOnly Property. Even though I was disposing the image (the local variable used by the ReadOnly Property) it wasn't releasing it.

Maybe because of the OnPropertyChanged implemented on my ViewModels, because when I made it a read/write property and I disposed of it and set it to null on every change of page, it was releasing the memory on the problematic computers.